# How to iterate worksheets in workbook - Scala - spoiwo/poi.apache.org

Tags: excel, scala, spoiwo

**I am trying to iterate worksheets in an Excel workbook.**
    I am using Scala's spoiwo/poi.apache

Here is the **documentation** in Java:

```
for (Sheet sheet : wb ) {
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            // Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I've tried.

```
def IterateSheets(): Unit ={
    var wb:XSSFWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    var sheet:XSSFSheet = wb.createSheet();
    sheet = wb.createSheet();
    sheet = wb.createSheet();
    for(sht:XSSFSheet <- wb ){
      println(sht.getSheetName());
    }
}
```

I am given the error:

```
Error:(28, 22) value filter is not a member of org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
for(sht:Sheet <- wb ){
```

I have also tried

```
for(sht:XSSFSheet <- wb.iterator() ){
```

And I don't see any workbook.sheetIterator() methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simple example of creating a sheet and displaying the list in Apache Poi and Scala. There is a `sheetIterator()` method in workbook.

```
  val myWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook()

  var sheets = myWorkbook.createSheet()

  sheets = myWorkbook.createSheet()

  val sheetItr = myWorkbook.sheetIterator()
  while (sheetItr.hasNext){
    println("******** " + sheetItr.next().getSheetName)
  }
```

Hope this helps!